# tanukisoft daemon wrapper and appassembler maven plugin - how to resolve conflicting jar names?

Tags: java, maven, conflict, appassembler, tanuki

I'm using the http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/ wrapper and have two jar files with the same artifactIds and the same version string, but different groupIds. Is there any way to prevent losing one of the two jar files when assembling the distribution zip, ie. use groupId as file name prefix?

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use the default repository layout instead of the flat one. When using the appassembler (jsw daemon gen) plugin together with the maven-assembly-plugin, one should make sure that one does not resolve the project classpath dependencies using the latter plugin because the appassembler does not know about the copy destination and cannot adjust the classpath accordingly, of course -- just include the lib/ dir output from the appassembler plugin in the final archive. In other words: don't use the dependencySet section in the binary descriptor for classpath dependencies (jars), but rather a fileSet section.